# MVC RegularExpression Model Attribute Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, model-binding, stringbuilder

I have a model, with a property and a `ReqularExpression` attribute that looks like this...

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{2}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Facility {NN CCY}")]
public string Facility { get; set; }
```

The partial view then simply has a text box using the above property...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Facility, new { @class = "form-control",
                                       placeholder = "Should be NN CCY, example: 01 EUR" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Facility)
```

The *Yellow Screen of death* is giving me this error:

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider,
>   String format, Object[] args) +14305394
>   System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[]
>   args) +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter.GetClientValidationRules()
>   +64    System.Linq.d__14`2.MoveNext() +267    System.Web.Mvc.UnobtrusiveValidationAttributesGenerator.GetValidationAttributes(IEnumerable`1
>   clientRules, IDictionary`2 results) +456
>   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(String
>   name, ModelMetadata metadata) +280

The fiels isn't populated with anything but the placeholder, and I get this error which highlights the `@Html.TextBoxForLine`. Removing the attribute solves the problem, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue by some further investigation, and [this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/appendformat) gave me a hint to the `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` where curly braces are used in the string.  My `ErrorMessage`, *"Invalid Facility {NN CCY}"* contains curly braces, and I replaced these with parenthesis and it now works.

*I'll leave this here for now in case others get a similar frustrating issue.*

Comment: curly braces can be used to add DisplayName value inside error message see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557953/how-to-put-displayname-on-errormessage-format

Comment: @ArjunVachhani , thanks, I will keep this in mind.  The error I was getting through was due to having the output use the curly braces just as _UI Formatting_, which wasn't required.