# How do I implement global required error message in c#?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field is Required")]
public string FirstName{ get; set; }
```

Instead of writing `(ErrorMessage = "This Field is Required")` above every property, can I set the ErrorMessage Globally?

Comment: What do you exactly want to implement?

Comment: I think just create another attribute class which extends `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute`. I can add an answer how to implement this if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set customized error message in all given required attributes without using `ErrorMessage` for each property, create an attribute class which derives from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute` and set default validation message in constructor part like below (credits to **[Chad Yeates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97154/chad-yeates)** for his advice):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomRequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public CustomRequiredAttribute()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "This Field is Required"; // custom error message here
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(name); // expandable to format given message later
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[CustomRequired]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Similar issues:

[MVC: Override default ValidationMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808097/mvc-override-default-validationmessage)

[how to put DisplayName on ErrorMessage format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557953/how-to-put-displayname-on-errormessage-format)